# Observable Angular2/4

Tags: angular, observable

my method  getUserInfo() returns Observable.How do I make the object in the interior of my observable changed and when I use my method  getUserInfo() got my modified object inside my observable?

```
getUserInfo():Observable<UserInfo>
  {
  return this.Obser;
}
```

here I get my object inside the observatory and overwrite it:

```
  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      let subscription = this.UserService.getUserInfo().subscribe( 
        value => (value = result)
    ); this.name = result.firstName+" "+result.lastName; this.data = result;
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: From what i could understand from the question, you want to change the value that the observable is emitting with the help of the subscriber.. Am i right?

Comment: Maybe use the map operator? Not at all clear on what the question is

Comment: @AmanArora Yes,And when I call the method getUserInfo() ,  I get the observed in it is my overwritten object

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make the object in the interior of my observable changed?

This is *exactly* what [the **`map` operator**](http://rxmarbles.com/#map) is for. If your observable emits users with fisrtName, lastName and age, you could do the following to get an observable of their full names:

```
this.UserService.getUserInfo()
  .map(user => `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`)
  .subscribe(fullName => this.name = fullName)
```

Comment: If I'm after this call the method getUserInfo() , I get observable with the modified object inside it?

Comment: The result of calling `map` will be a stream where every emitted value is transformed by the function you give it. Then, you subscribe to this new stream returned by `map`.

Comment: I wrote via the Map but nothing changed when I called getUserInfo () after I used the Map then everything was reset before

Comment: Please read some sort of introduction to observables. You cannot use Angular without it.